# Can you disable rotation globally in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app made up of a lot of view controllers...  in the project summary I've set Portrait orientation as the only supported device orientation.

However, the app still gets messed up when turned sideways.

My question is, is there a way to globally disable autorotation through app delegate or something?

Or do I have to go into all of my view controllers and add the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" method?

Just don't want to miss adding it to one or something...

Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while since I've done iOS, but isn't there something you can put in the app plist?  Something about "supported orientations" or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in root view controller's method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

set 'return NO';

this should do for all the Views.

Comment: Depricated now.

Answer (score 75):

In Info.plist expand "Supported interface orientations" and remove Landscape items to make your application only run in portrait mode.

Answer (score 25):

There are three kinds of Device orientation keys there in the `info.plist` now.

1. Supported interface orientations (iPad)
2. Supported interface orientations (iPhone)
3. Supported interface orientations

Third one is I think for non-universal apps and rest two above are for iPad and iPhone.

You should give them a try.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is the only thing I needed to do to force portrait only for both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Perfect.Thanks.

Comment: This is the best approach for iOS. Apple's look-and-feel asks that iPad apps support all orientations. This way allows separate settings for the phone.

Answer (score 14):

After struggling to set in UIViewController's  `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientation` methods, with no success in iOS6, I found the most effective is to set it in app delegate.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

However returning `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown` was crashing my app. I dont know whats wrong I was doing!

Comment: This works for iOS 8 too. Worked perfectly for me in combination with supported interface orientation setting set in the App's `Info.plist` file

Answer (score 3):

If you're supporting iPad, then you SHOULD NOT uncheck the landscape orientations, as it will prevent your app from being accepted by Apple on App Store.

To prevent rotating before the app shows your first screen, put this inside your AppDelegate.m

This method works and tested in iOS 7.1 above.

```
// G - fix for ipad.
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haris Hussain's answer appears to be deprecated now, as of IOS 6, but there are new methods available for limiting/enabling rotation.

Here are the methods listed in the UIViewController header:

```
// New Autorotation support.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
// Returns interface orientation masks.
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Note that shouldAutoRotate doesn't seem to work if you start the app in an already rotated state!

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**
**iOS 6+**

The recommended way is to override `shouldAutorotate` in every attached view controller. If you override this property in the root view controller, then all "attached" view controllers will also inherit the behavior. Presented view controllers, however, can become "unattached" to the root and thus would not inherit the override and so you would need to override the property in those view controllers separately.

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool { false }
}

class PresentedViewController: UIViewController {
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool { false }
}
```

However, if you simply subclass `UIViewController` and only use the subclassed view controllers in your project then you have a truly global fix (using code).

```
class NonrotatableViewController: UIViewController {
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool { false }
}
```

**Settings alternative (no code)**

Perhaps the most global fix is editing the Info.plist file in the info tab in the target's settings. There is a supported-interface-orientations key with each value representing a supported orientation. Deleting all but portrait will disable rotation in all view controllers, attached or unattached to the root.

Answer (score -1):

Project navigator > "Your Project" > “General” > “Deployment info” > Device Orientation

### Just check what you want and uncheck what you don't.

Second and Best Solution Xcode 15:
Project Navigator > Your Project > Targets > Info > Custom iOS Target Properties > Supported interface orientations

Just Open and make your adjustment:
**Item 0 ---------- Portrait (bottom home button)**

Delete or add other options you want

Comment: The first sentence of the question states that only Portrait is selected.

Comment: Second Solution: 
Project Navigator > Your Project > Targets > Info > Custom iOS Target Properties > Supported interface orientations

Just Open and make your adjustment:
Item 0 ---------- Portrait (bottom home button)
Delete or add other options you want