# How can I remove the rotation of the screen?

Tags: ios, rotation

I am developing an ios application, which should stay always vertical and I should disable the functions, users to rotate their screens. Would you advise me how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you disable rotation globally in an iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125050/can-you-disable-rotation-globally-in-an-ios-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Info.plist expand "Supported interface orientations" and remove Landscape items to make your application only run in portrait mode.
Taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087248/4279419).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Remove 2 check marks in Deployment info landscape left and landscape right in your project.